# Problems with VS Code application icon

Tags: spotlight, icon, apple-silicon

I have downloaded [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) on my new Mac mini, but the icon seems to be some random dots. My Mac mini has the M1 Chip.

Here is a picture of the icon in Spotlight:
[image: Image of Spotlight]

A few steps I have tried:

- Restarting the Mac
- Reinstalling VS Code
- Trying with a different user
- Contacted Apple Support, response was, "it is not our product (vs code) so we can no fix it"

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Is the icon the same in the Dock, in Launchpad, in Get Info? If you right-click on the app and Show Contents, then navigate into the Resources folder, can you see the icon file anywhere? What's that like? TBH, if it's just a cosmetic issue, I wouldn't worry: it'll get fixed in an upgrade to the OS or the app.

Comment: @benwiggey Yes, it's the same everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. The OS is displaying the image file incorrectly.
2. The image file itself is corrupt.

If you can find an application that uses different routines to display the image file, then you may be able to rule out the first option, if you can get the image to display correctly in a third-party app.

Otherwise, it's an issue for the developer.

Comment: The LaunchServive database may be damaged. Would it be smart to rebuild it?

Comment: Nice idea. But would that affect the Get Info icon, and the icon file inside the app bundle itself?

Comment: Not correct with application packages because icons are already defined in the resources. Maybe you could see if something was changed in Contents/MacOS/Resources. If this only appears in Spotlight, the Spotlight database may simply be defective. If you're wondering what an app without a resource looks like, here's an example /System/Library/CoreServices/AirPlayUIAgent.app Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you're saying. Would LSdb affect the actual icon file in the app bundle?